# How to use mutex to sync this secuence: (A or B)C (A or B) (A or B)C

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads, mutex

i'm learning about sync with mutex and have this problem. I need 3 threads, each one print a letter and i've to print the secuence from te tittle in an infinite loop. The idea its that A and B thread make the same thing except the print. My idea was to use a trylock with initial value 1, AorB mutex initial value 1 and C mutex initial value 0. but then realise it only work the first iteration and then write alway 2 (AorB)... Its posible to solve it in this way?

```
void *rutA(){ //Rut B its the same but print B
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&semAoB);
        printf("A");
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
        if(sem_trywait(&turnoC) == 0){//(AorB)
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&semC);
        }else{////(AorB)(AorB)
            sem_post(&turnoC);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexAoB);
        }

    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

 void *rutC(){
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexC);
        printf("C");
        sleep(1);
        fflush(stdout);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&semAoB);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't unlock a mutex in a different thread than the one that locked it.

You can solve this problem either using sempahores, or using mutexes and condition variables - but you should probably not mix the two approaches.

Here's an example of solving it using a mutex and condition variable pair:

```
int state = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *runA(void *arg)
{
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while (state == 1 || state == 4)
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);

        putchar('A');
        fflush(stdout);
        if (++state > 4)
            state = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *runB(void *arg)
{
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while (state == 1 || state == 4)
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);

        putchar('B');
        fflush(stdout);
        if (++state > 4)
            state = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *runC(void *arg)
{
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while (state == 0 || state == 2 || state == 3)
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);

        putchar('C');
        fflush(stdout);
        if (++state > 4)
            state = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but yes i can because all threads are created for the same parent... I think that with variable its not correct.

Comment: No, it is not correct for a thread to unlock a mutex that it did not lock itself, regardless of which thread created it.  POSIX is quite clear on this point: the result is either undefined behaviour or an error return.

Comment: I have included an example to show how you could solve it using a mutex and condition variable.